# Generalization of the inequality $ab\leq \frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2)$

Tags: inequality

Let $a, b, c, d, e$ are positive real numbers and let $f$ be a negative real number. Do we have
$$ \vert abc+def \vert \leq \frac{1}{2}\vert(a^2 +b^2)c+ (d^2+e^2)f   \vert ~?$$

I tried to produce a counter example but...

Comment: The c,f have indefinite sign which could make the RHS vanish. Say $(a,b)$ and $(d,e)$ are on the unit circle, $c=1,f=-1$, can you now choose angles to make the LHS positive?

Answer (score 5):

Try $a=b=d=c=1$, $e=2$, $f=-0.4$ and we get

$$0.2\leq 0$$

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly more interesting example, consider
$$
a=63,b=16, c=1, \\
d=33, e=56, f=-1
$$
Using the fact that $65$ is the hypotenuse of two distinct integer-sided right triangles.

On the other hand, if we required that all variables are $>0$, I think the inequality would hold.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can always choose $f$ so that the right side is zero. By choosing $d$ and $e$ small, you can ensure that the left side is non-zero.

Comment: So $f$ depends on $d, e$ and $d, e$ depend on $f$? That might be unsuccessful...

Comment: Youare meaning the right side is no-zero

Comment: No. I mean the left side in non-zero and, by choosing f, the right side is zero.